# Why google video player randomly gives exception

Tags: flash, adsense

```
any ideas? Why the google video player randomly gives exception, how can I fix it?
This problem suddenly started this week or so.

    SecurityError: Error #2047: Security sandbox violation: parent: my.swf cannot access 
    http://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/player-vflqv4MLv/watch_as3.swf.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/get parent()
    at fl.managers::FocusManager/isTabVisible()
    at fl.managers::FocusManager/tabEnabledChangeHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at com.google.youtube.ui::UIElement/onAddedToStage()
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.common.video::YouTubeChromelessPlaybackImpl/play()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.vast.ui::AbstractVideoAdRenderer/usePlaybackToPlayVideo()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.vast.ui::AbstractVideoAdRenderer/start()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.common::AbstractVpaidAd/start()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.common.video::AbstractVideoAd/start()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.common::VpaidAdsManagerImpl/startCurrentAd()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.common::VpaidAdsManagerImpl/startInternal()
    at com.google.ads.ima.common::AbstractAdsManager/start()
    at com.google.ads.ima.formats.common::VpaidAdsManagerImpl/redispatchAdEventHandler()
    at com.google.ads.ima.common::AbstractAdsManager/adEventHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventF
```

Answer (score 1):

just try this steps:

In Flash IDE by going to File->Publish Settings->Flash->Local playback security and choosing either ‘Access local files only’ or ‘Access network only’.

In FlashDevelop by right clicking on your project->Properties->Compiler Options->Use network services

In Amethyst by right clicking on the project in the solution explorer->Properties->Compiler->Use network

taked from: [here](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2012/11/05/fixing-security-sandbox-violation-in-flash-as3/)